# Mute conversations on KakaoTalk

Tags: windows-7, kakaotalk

Is it possible to mute a conversation on KakaoTalk for Windows? I would like not to be notified when new messages arrive in a given conversation (but I still want message notifications for other conversations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible to mute a conversation on KakaoTalk for Windows.